# Background size doesnt scale when i use a value of cover

Tags: html, css

```css
html ,body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0px;
}

h1 {
  margin:50px;
}

.jumbotron {
  height:100%;
  background-image: url("http://www.zoophotels.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/cpt-new.jpg");
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Welcome</h1>      
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't know what's wrong, but it seems like when i change `background-size` value to `cover`, the background doesn't scale based on my browser size, but when i set the value to `100% 100%`, it scales like i expect.

So, how to keep the value of cover and let `jumbotron` class do the right scale (in this case keep the value of background size (`cover`), while the size when `jumbotron` do scaling still `cover`)

Additional Info:

i want the result to be

1.The image cover to be like 100% 100% (fit to screen)

2.When i resizing my browser window, i want the image ratio still same like 1 step

check this web: http://www.qerja.com/ 
i want the jumbotron looks like this website jumbotron, resize the image width when i resizing the browser windows

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using google chrome

Comment: `the background doesn't scale based on my browser size` it's scale. Try to  resize your browser's height. When you use `100% 100%` the image's proportions are wrong and the image is distorted. Can you add to the question screenshots with the problem + the expected result?

Comment: actually i want the result to be 
1.The image size to be like 100% 100%(fit to screen)
2.When i resizing my browser window, i want the size ratio still same like the 1

Comment: in this case you need to take 2 different images one for landscape screens and second for portrait i am sure there is no other way to handle this problem

Comment: might be your problem will solve this jquery plugin http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Resize-Images-To-Fit-In-A-Container-imgLiquid/examples/

Comment: @KevinMogi your code is working on my browser, the cover take 100 percent of my screen

Comment: actually i want to make my ratio of image still same with original ratio, and display it as a cover......the problem now is that i display it as a cover, but the aspect ration is not same with the original image ratio(there are some trees that i cant see)

Answer (score 0):

Cover is working as expected. The image maintain's it's aspect ratio as it scales in relation to your browser window. Unlike applying 100% 100%.

> Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the
>   background area is completely covered by the background image. Some
>   parts of the background image may not be in view within the background
>   positioning area

[CSS3 background-size Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Comment: i see...
but now i want,

1.The image cover to be like 100% 100% (fit to screen).
2.When i resizing my browser window, i want the image ratio still same like 1 step. How to solve this?

Comment: background-position:center center; background-size:cover;